# Including child class into basic C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have three classes:
`BaseClass`, that contains `ElementClass` as field
`ElementClass`, that contains `BaseClass` as field and `ChildClass` as return type (pointer) 
`ChildClass`, that's inherits from `BaseClass`. 
When I'm trying to compile this, I am getting 
`expected class-name before '{' token`
for `ChildClass`, that was included in `ElementClass`, that was included in `BaseClass`. 
I understand, why is this happens. Because I'm trying to inherit child class from nonexistent, for compiler, class `BaseClass`.
I can't understand hot to fix this. Thank you.
Here is code example with this problem
**BaseClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H

#include "ElementClass.h"

class ElementClass;

class BaseClass
{

private:
    ElementClass *m_someField;
};


#endif
```

**ElementClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H

#include "ChildClass.h"

class ChildClass;

class ElementClass
{
private:
    ChildClass *m_class;
};


#endif
```

**ChildClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_CHILDCLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_CHILDCLASS_H

#include "BaseClass.h"

class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{

};


#endif
```

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Comment: 1. sounds like your class design could use more work, 2. forward declaration.

Comment: 3. show actual code instead of describing how the code looks like.

Comment: If `BaseClass` contains one `ElementClass` field and if `ElementClass` contains one  `BaseClass` field, the program is ill-formed and will not compile. C++ will only accept a fully defined class for a member.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I meant, that fields are pointers to objects.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I have another problem. I have problem with inherit, not with cycle pointer fields.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Hm. It's pretty big, so I'll try to make small alternative. If I'll can't I will post all my code.

Comment: @lispHK01 Ok. Edited question with sample project, introducing this "problem"

Comment: @bolov Added example code with this "problem" that is not compiling.

Comment: @Megaxela No you didn't, your BaseClass.h and ChildClass.h are identical

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh... I am idiot. Fixed it.

Comment: Your problem is probably, that you are indirectly including `ChildClass.h` in `BaseClass.h`, resulting in you trying to define `ChildClass` before `BaseClass`. Just remove the extra `#include`s and only use forward declarations. Only include you need here is `BaseClass.h` in `ChildClass.h` (since that's not a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

> BaseClass, that contains ElementClass as field
>
> ElementClass, that contains BaseClass as field

So, a `BaseClass` instance contains an `ElementClass` instance which contains a `BaseClass` instance which contains an `ElementClass` instance which contains... instances all the way down. One instance is going to use all of your memory and then some. That cannot work.

It also cannot work because when defining the first class, you need to have a complete definition of the second class, which needs a complete definition of the first class, which wasn't defined yet.

You must use indirection. At least one of the classes must not contain the other instance inside, but instead a pointer or a reference to an instance.

Comment: I tried to answer by quoting my own answer inside itself. You beat me to the punch. I'm stil copy-pasting...